# How can I send onesignal notification between two devices

Tags: push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, onesignal

I want to send a onesignal notification from a button in android studio to another device using device tokens. But I am not getting it. What is the proper way of doing?

I want event to be trigger by the button not by onesignal dashboard

```
SendNotificationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    
//code to send notification to another device.

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OneSignal REST API (see [Send to Specific Devices](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification#send-to-specific-devices) in the documentation)